# How can I make apt pull an older dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, dependencies, mx-linux

**Edit:** I never found a solution to my specific issue, but as soon as I hopped onto Linux Mint I was able to install this package. So if you run into this same issue with this particular package/dependency issue, try an Ubuntu-based distro.

I am currently trying to install the package [libboost1.71-all-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/libboost1.71-all-dev) with apt on my MX Linux machine. However, apt is unable to meet all of the dependencies for this package. I get the following information:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-mpi-python1.71.0 : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.9.2-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've never run into apt pulling a more recent dependency than  is required (and that being an issue). I'm curious if there's a way to force apt to target the correct python3 version, or maybe a way to make apt ignore this dependency? What is the best way to go about resolving this issue?

I've tried manually downloading this [python3 (3.7.3-1)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3) package, and pulling into the package installer. However, this throws the error "A later version is already installed".

Here are the repo's I currently have active:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirrors.rit.edu/mxlinux/mx-packages/mx/repo/ bullseye main non-free
deb http://mirrors.rit.edu/mxlinux/mx-packages/mx/repo/ bullseye ahs
```

Comment: Does `apt-mark showhold ` return any held packages?

Comment: @doneal24 nothing shows held when I run that command

Comment: You might be out of luck. That looks like a rather old version of libboost (Debian stable has 1.74), and for some reason depends on an (also) old version of python3, that is not easily installable on your MX linux, that doesn't seem to be as old as those packages. I don't know libboost, but I would try to make do with the version that MX (probably) supplies.

Comment: Install a Debian 10 container, add a buster-backports repository and do this from the Debian 10 container.